# Arrow operator in the constructor of a class C++

Tags: c++, constructor, hashtable, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

I am working in a Hash Table in C++ and I wanted it to be dynamically allocated to support a case where the table might be declared with a very large size.

The code is working and it looks like:

```
class HashTable {
private:
    static const int m_TableSize = 4;

    struct item {
        std::string name;
        std::string drink;
        item* next;
    };

    item* m_Table;

public:
    HashTable();
    ~HashTable();
};

HashTable::HashTable()
{
    m_Table = new item[m_TableSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_TableSize; i++)
    {
        m_Table[i].name = "empty";
        m_Table[i].drink = "empty";
        m_Table[i].next = nullptr;
    }
}

HashTable::~HashTable() {
    delete[] m_Table;
}
```

Here's my question:
Even though I am using the new keyword and the table is defined as an array of pointers `item*` wouldn't it be necessary, in the constructor, to use the arrow operator to access the member variables inside `m_Table`  as in the line below?

```
m_Table[i]->name = "empty";
```

Initially, I tried to use the arrow operator, but I got a compiler error: "type 'HashTable::item' does not have an overloaded 'member operator ->' ".

Comment: The "arrow" operator is to dereference a pointer to an object, and access its member. Say you have `item *pointer = new item;` Then you can use the arrow operator as in `item->name`. It will be equivalent to `(*item).name`. When you use `m_Table[i]->name` it's the same as `(*m_Table[i]).name` which makes no sense since `m_Table[i]` is not a pointer.

Comment: "the table is defined as an array of pointers `item*`". Not so. `m_Table` is defined as a single pointer `item*`, which might point to an array of elements of type `item`.

Comment: If `name` is part of the key that is hashed in order to calculate the item's index in your hash table, then I would say it's a rather bad idea to modify it. If you just want empty values, why would you set them to the string "empty"? Just use empty strings. You can value-initialize the entire table on allocation as follows: `m_Table = new item[m_TableSize]();` -- your strings are empty anyway, but this ensures your `next` pointer is also NULL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Indeed, it wasn't clear to me that `m_Table` was being declared as a single pointer.

Comment: On another note, what if the user of your class want's to add an element with the key `"empty"`? How would you distinguish it from your own "empty" elements? Wouldn't it be better to just let the strings be default-initialized (and empty)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, in first place, in this specific case, the key is supposed to link the name of a person with some other information, so the name `empty` would be rather weird. 
Secondly, I chose to initialize the strings as empty just to make it easier in a future AddItem method in order to check if that bucket has already some key stored in it, but I think it would be possible as well to leave them default-initialized.

Comment: Well, checking `if (m_Table[i].name.empty())` is a little more efficient than `if (m_Table[i].name == "empty)`... ;)

Comment: This comment is not replying the original question. I am rather targeting a major flaw in your design. According to rule of 0/3/5, now that you have a none-trivial destructor, you must properly define copy constructor and assignment operator as well. If this were not an exercise program I would recommend not to reinvent the wheel. You can simply use `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>`.

Comment: @Red.Wave To be clear, it is an exercise program and I do not intend to reivent the wheel. I appreciate the warning. Would you mind attaching a link with the reference to this specific rule?

Comment: @AcKoucher. This rule is very versatile. Just google it; include C++ in your keywords. It is one of the fundamental idioms of C++.

Answer (score 2):

`m_Table` is declared as an array of item objects, not an array of item pointers. to access the member variables of `m_Table[i]`, you should use `m_Table[i].name` instead of `m_Table[i]->name` to access the name member variable of the i-th element in the array.

I think the reason you got a compiler error with `->` is that the item struct does not have any pointers as member variables -- The next member variable is itself an item object, not a pointer to an item object. If you had defined next as an item* pointer, you could use `->` to access its member variables.